# HLS on nginx, not stopping as expected

Tags: nginx, mp4, http-live-streaming, m3u8

Using https://gist.github.com/45sound/bd2a5ee699e428d63bcd as http://54.204.158.100/1.m3u8 (you also can download it directly)

http://54.204.158.100/hls/clock.mp4 is the source mp4.

http://54.204.158.100/hls/clock.mp4.ts?start=0.0&end=4.99 is the segment to play.

In the osmfhls.kutu.ru player, this plays for 6.99 seconds instead of 4.99.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Nginx HLS module is configured to server `7s` fragments. The actual duration is `7.180s`:

`curl "http://<ip_address>/hls/clock.mp4.m3u8"`

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:7
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD

#EXTINF:7.200,
clock.mp4.ts?start=0.000&end=7.200
#EXTINF:7.200,
clock.mp4.ts?start=7.200&end=14.400
#EXTINF:5.400,
clock.mp4.ts?start=14.400&end=19.800
...
```

In the case of `http://<ip_address>/hls/clock.mp4.ts?start=0.0&end=4.99` request, if the player ignores the query string after the `.ts` then it will play just the first segment for a total duration of `7.180s` as configured in the module. Check the Nginx `access.log` to see what it requested.

**Update**

After checking the specs of the `mp4` file I noticed you use a `GOP` size of `60` at a frame rate of `25`. This means `1` keyframe every `60 / 25 = 2.4` seconds. When you pass the URL with the `start` and `end` query string to Nginx it apparently tries to return the full portion between two keyframes and it doesn't cut on the exact timestamp.

In case of `start = 1.0` and `end = 2.2` this doesn't work because the first full interval is between `0.0` and `2.4`. For `start = 0` and `end = 4.99` it will play from `0.0` to `7.2` since `2.4 x 2 = 4.8` which is smaller than `4.99`.

The documentation doesn't say if this is the desired behavior. In general,  to avoid issues, you have to set *a target duration equal to a multiple of your keyframe interval*.

Comment: That's very interesting re 7 second segment, you are correct.


I tried playing the following segments in VLC 2.2 on Ubuntu:
[http://54.204.158.100/hls/clock.mp4.ts?start=1.000&end=2.200](http://54.204.158.100/hls/clock.mp4.ts?start=1.000&end=2.200)  (not working)

[http://54.204.158.100/hls/clock.mp4.ts?start=0&end=4.99](http://54.204.158.100/hls/clock.mp4.ts?start=0&end=4.99)    (shows 6+7 seconds)

Any idea why this may be? This is using the Nginx Plus server to serve the videos

Comment: Updated the answer with a possible cause.

Comment: I downloaded the clock.mp4 and gave it a keyframe every second:
ffmpeg -i clock.mp4 -g 1 clock_keyframe_every_frame.mp4   


I uploaded it to 
[http://54.204.158.100/hls/clock_keyframe_every_frame.mp4](http://54.204.158.100/hls/clock_keyframe_every_frame.mp4)    


and changed the m3u8 as per this gist
[https://gist.github.com/45sound/fd8c765d34cd6c9dd867](https://gist.github.com/45sound/fd8c765d34cd6c9dd867) . Also available at [http://54.204.158.100/keyframe_every_second.m3u8](http://54.204.158.100/keyframe_every_second.m3u8)     


The mp4 file plays fine, but not when I use the m3u8.

Comment: Trying to play `http://54.204.158.100/hls/clock_keyframe_every_frame.mp4.m3u8` (the Nginx provided `m3u8`) results in a HTTP 500 Internal Server Error. Check the `error.log`.

Comment: You're welcome. You should still ask on the Nginx forum about the `start` and `end` behavior. It's weird not being able to seek to any position.